# Drupal Commerce product sale price using Rules

Tags: commerce, rules

I tried Rules like explained here [enter link description here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39743/drupal-commerce-sale-price/171607?noredirect=1#answer-39749). It works but when it comes to checkout, order total amount displays 0. I've got no clue why. Here is my rule:

```
{ "rules_sale_price" : {
    "LABEL" : "\u0426\u0435\u043d\u0430 \u0441\u043e \u0441\u043a\u0438\u0434\u043a\u043e\u0439",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "sale price" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_product_reference" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ], "field" : "commerce_product" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product" ],
          "field" : "field_produkt_sale_price"
        }
      },
      { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-produkt-sale-price" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-unit-price" ],
          "value" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-produkt-sale-price" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right way to do this: In the rule action I used **Set the unit price to a specific amount** instead of **Set a data value**.